# Autorização de usuários a actions que utilizam o atributo Authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Eu coloquei o `[Authorize]` nos meus *controllers* e inseri este código:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Login/Login" />
</authentication>`
```

Para sempre que ocorrer o código 401 ele redirecionar para a página de login, porém não sei como faço no *controller* `LOGIN` para atribuir acesso a pessoa.

Meu problema é o seguinte, ele redireciona para o login, porém ao fazer o login ele continua sem acesso, provavelmente falta alguma coisa no meu LOGIN.

Segue abaixo meu Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login(Usuario usuario)
    {
        if (usuario.Nome == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            var user = db.Usuario.Where(u => u.Nome == usuario.Nome && u.Senha.Equals(usuario.Senha)).First();

            if (user.Nome.Equals(null))
            {
                ViewBag.Mensagem = "Usuário ou Senha Inválido, tente novamente!";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Home");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como assim informar? Se o usuário acessar ele já está autorizado, não?

Comment: Não consegui compreender muito bem o que você quis dizer. Você poderia elaborar melhor sua pergunta? Seria interessante também que você melhorasse esse título para deixa-lo mais específico, irá facilitar para outros usuários encontrar a sua pergunta caso tenham a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos tentar lhe ajudar um pouco mais.

Neste parte de seu código, você apenas está verificando se exite um usuário cadastrado em seu banco de dados com esse login e senha. Porém, em nenhum momento você realmente "autentica" o usuário:

```
var user = db.Usuario.Where(u => u.Nome == usuario.Nome && u.Senha.Equals(usuario.Senha)).First();
```

Você pode alterar isso, simplesmente adicionando essa parte em seu código:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(Usuario model, string returnUrl)
        {
            var user = db.Usuarios.First(u => u.Login == model.Login && u.Senha.Equals(model.Senha));

            //verifica se possui usuário
            if (user != null)
            {
                //adiciona cookie de autenticação 
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Login, model.LembrarMe);

                //verifica se possui o uma url para retornar ou se está na página logOn
                if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }



            // Mensagem de erro caso nãoa che usuário
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login ou senha incorretos");
            return View(model);
        }
```

Dessa forma você poderá utilizar o atributo `[authorize]` como já está fazendo.
Lembrando que você está utilizando o [FormsAuthentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication(v=vs.110).aspx) para realizar a autenticação.

Atualmente, a Microsoft possui um excelente Framework para realizar isso, chamada de [Asp.Net Identity.](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) Ela já possui as configurações necessárias para autenticação, controle de acesso, autenticação por redes sociais, dentre outras opções.

Se quiser saber mais sobre, deixarei alguns links com tutorias (em inglês) sobre.

### Links

- [Entendendo o Identity](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics)
- [Two Factor Authentication (SMS e E-Mail)](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity)
- [Autenticação com redes sociais](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

Comment: Obrigado, preciso de algo simples por enquanto, pois esse sistema é de estágio supervisionado da faculdade e estou com pouco tempo.

Comment: O que seria essa parte do Código ´ model.LembrarMe);´ ?

Comment: @J.C.Galhardi ele guarda a informação que você deseja que o browse lembra que você está logado, mesmo fechando a página. Igual o "permanecer conectado" do Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Possivelmente não está passando as variáveis porque você não indicou que é uma *Action* `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Usuario usuario)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa de duas *Actions* uma apenas para retorna a *View* de *login* e outra para realizar a tentativa de *login* (verificando os dados de usuário e senha) e o redirecionamento.

Mas no seu código existem alguns problemas, você não tem essas duas *Actions* e também não está realizando a autenticação do usuário quando o usuário e senha estão corretos, o processo de autenticação adiciona um *cookie* no navegador do usuário que será utilizado pelo *framework* para saber se ele poderá ou não acessar *Actions* que foram decoradas com o atributo `Authorize`.

Para adicionar esse *cookie* no navegador do usuário você pode utilizar o método [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie(v=vs.110).aspx). De uma olhada no exemplo abaixo onde realizo um processo completo de autenticação de usuário.

```
    public ActionResult SignIn(string returnUrl = "/")
    {
        // Apenas retorna a View login
        return View(new UserSignInViewModel
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn(UserSignInViewModel viewModel, string returnUrl = "/")
    {
        // Retorna a View de login novamente caso exista dados incorretos no model
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        try
        {
            // Aqui estou procurando no banco por pelo usuário e senha fornecidos, isso aqui é muito específico para esse exemplo, você deverá fazer essa verificação da sua maneira
            var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(u => u.UsernameUpper, viewModel.Username.ToUpper()) & Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Password, viewModel.Password);
            var user = await ZigBlogDb.Users.Find(filter).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            // Caso eu não encontre retorno a mesma View de login com um erro dizendo que o usuário e/ou a senha estão incorretos
            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Translation.UserSignInError);
                return View();
            }

            // Caso eu encontre adiciono o cookie no navegador do usuário passando o nome do usuário como primeiro argumento, e no segundo argumento eu especifico se esse cookie deverá permanecer além dessa sessão
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, viewModel.RememberMe);

            // No final eu realizo o redirecionamento
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("Error", new SharedErrorViewModel(ex));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esse código acima pertence a qual controller?

Comment: É o código de uma *controller* de *login*.

Comment: Olha quem tá vivo :)